# Spring WebFlux handler for kotlin SharedFlow

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I can see the following example working in Spring WebFlux handler for a flow builder:

```kotlin
suspend fun getDummyFlow(req: ServerRequest): ServerResponse {
    val flow = flow<String> { // flow builder
        for (i in 1..3) {
            delay(1000) // pretend we are doing something useful here
            emit("<p>Hello $i</p>") // emit next value
        }
    }
    return ServerResponse
        .ok()
        .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
        .bodyAndAwait(flow)
}
```

Yet, I need to build a flow with a `MutableSharedFlow` which is not working in Spring Web Flux. Here it is an example:

```kotlin
suspend fun getDummyFlow(req: ServerRequest): ServerResponse {
    return coroutineScope {
        val flow = MutableSharedFlow<String>()
        launch {
            for (i in 1..3) {
                delay(1000) // pretend we are doing something useful here
                flow.emit("<p>Hello $i</p>") // emit next value
            }
        }
        ServerResponse
            .ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
            .bodyAndAwait(
                flow
                    .asSharedFlow()
                    .take(3)
            )
    }
```

My implementation is based on the example of [SharedFlow](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/) documentation.

Yet, any HTTP GET request to this endpoint stays pending and waiting for a response, whereas the former example with flow builder receives the response progressively and fine.

I have already traced my code in debug and I see `.bodyAndAwait(..)` being called and then `emit()` in both cases.